# Can we send command for Quectel M66 from STM32F103C8T6 via UART port?

Tags: stm32, uart, freertos, quectel

I am currently working with STM32F103C8T6 and Quectel M66 module. I need to send some command from STM32's UART port for creating a socket connection in M66 and to send some data via that socket to a server in Quectel M66. Is there any way to do that? And I am using FreeRTOS for this.
          And what kind of data are possible to send via UART port of STM32?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by **what kind of data**. UART support **8 Bit** data transfer either of **char Type* or of **uint8_t** type. Generally **char** is also **8 Bit** data.

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways you can achieve this:

1. Using AT commands and TCP/IP stack built into the module. In this mode you send AT commands to connect/listen/send/receive/close sockets.
2. Using PPP and TCP/IP stack inside the microcontroller. In this mode you initially configure the modem using AT commands (which you have to do in both approaches anyway), then you switch the modem to data mode, at which point it starts communicating with you using PPP protocol. You use this to integrate it with the TCP/IP stack in your microcontroller. That way you use all the functionality of the stack you choose (socket API, DNS etc.) and you're not limited to what API quectel provided. You can also take advantage of having multiple network interfaces connected to your microcontroller, for example to perform routing.

How you approach it is totally up to you. If you want just the basic socket functionality, first approach will probably be better for you as it's easier to get it to work. Second approach takes quite a bit more effort but yields better results / more flexible product for the future.

For AT commands documentation check out this link (especially the TCP/IP application note): https://www.quectel.com/product/m66.htm

Comment: Can I send AT commands to M66 via UART port as a string ( I mean uint8_t data type). Would M66 understand that?                                                                                        
        For example: UART_Transmit(&handler,"AT+QIOPEN",sizeof(AT+QIOPEN));                        Is it right?

Comment: You'll probably need to do line end to the command (making it "AT+QIOPEN\r\n") but yes, that's exactly what you do. AT commands are essentially a text based protocol.